# VBScript - catching End Task signal

Tags: windows, vbscript, signals, interrupt, taskmanager

I have a script written in VBS that checks every second if the LAN port has a connection and if so, disables the wireless, or enables the wireless if no LAN connection exists.  There's an unfortunate bug in this that leaves the wireless disabled if you shut down the computer while this script is running that I would like to fix.  The script runs at logon via a GPO, so it won't run if one logs in off the network.

Is it at all possible to catch the End Task signal and perform cleanup operations before the script ends?  I'd like for this to re-enable the wireless as the system shuts down.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No i think it is not possible and if so it would be unreliable or slow down your pc i'm afraid. But just as you can have a script running at logon you can also have a script running at logoff, i suggest you take that road.